# How can I stop my whole job from parallel flow?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a job with 2 flows

```
Flow parallelFlow = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("parallelFlow")
    .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
    .add(flow1, flow2)
    .build();
```

flow1 contains step1 which stops the job using `stepExecution.setTerminateOnly()` after 5s

```
public class Step1 implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(@NotNull StepContribution stepContribution, @NotNull ChunkContext chunkContext) throws InterruptedException, NoSuchJobExecutionException, JobExecutionNotRunningException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        stepContribution.getStepExecution().setTerminateOnly();
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

flow2 contains step2 which only waits 10s and step3 with some logic

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Step2 implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(@NotNull StepContribution stepContribution,@NotNull ChunkContext chunkContext) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

I tried to stop the job and I expect the job was stopped and step3 was never executed.

In this case my job was stopped but step3 was executed.

But if I change flows order to `flow2, flow1` it will work like a charm!

```
Flow parallelFlow = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("parallelFlow")
    .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
    .add(flow2, flow1)
    .build();
```

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong

Java version 11, Spring batch version 4.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: `I change flows order to flow2, flow1 it will work like a charm!`: Interesting. Since those flows are going to be executed in parallel, the registration order should not matter. Please open an issue with a reference to this SO question and attach a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and I will investigate this issue in details. Thank you upfront.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure if you could stop a job from a parallel flow (as the title of your question suggests). I mean once you launch several steps in parallel, you would need to wait for them to complete to decide if the job should be stopped. The part I'm not sure of is how Spring Batch will propagate the stop signal from one step to other steps running in parallel at the same time.